# C++ - Optional arguments by reference

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value, parameter-passing

I have an exam on C++ coming up, and I'm solving a few ones from past years. I have this question in one of them:

> A function calculates the volume of a
>   prysm. Arguments passed are height,
>   depth and width. Arguments and return value are doubles
>   Depth is optional and
>   should default to 10. 
>   Hypothesis 1:
>   All parameters are passed by value

I answered `double volume_prysm(const double width, const double height, const double depth = 10);`

> Hypothesis 2:
>   All parameters are passed by reference

How can I define a reference parameter in order for it to default to 10?

Thanks for your time!

PS: Sorry y'all for not translating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that is what the question was aiming at, but temporaries can be bound to const references:

```
double volume_prisma(const double& largura, ..., const double& depth = 10);
```

Comment: `double volume_prisma(const double & largura, const double & altura, const double & profundidade = 10);` then?

Comment: @Francisco: Yep, i took the liberty of ommiting the rest.

Comment: One problem I see here is that I'd think the point of assigning a reference to a parameter's value is to make it an optional value. If the argument is defined as a const, any attempt to modify it within the function will fail. Only way I've found around this is: DON'T make the arg const, but assign it to a globally declared dummy variable of the same type. That way if the caller passes their own argument, it will be the one getting modified instead of the dummy.